# Can I print to the Windows console data that always displays?

Tags: c++, windows, console

I have a console program where I'd like to display some state in the first few lines, while keeping it's ordinary input/output logging behavior with the remaining lines.

I've tried to illustrate it here:

```
+-----------------------------+  <-+
/ state1: abcdef              /    | // this always stays at the top of the console
/ state2: 012345              /    | // this is the behavior that deviates from normal
+-----------------------------+  <-+ 
1st input  ^                       <-+ 
2nd input  |                         | // this scrolls upward as usual for the console
3rd input  |                         | // displaying past inputs/outputs
4th input  |                       <-+
5th in_                          <-- // normal console input + carot
```

I've tried outputing the entire console window's contents to simulate this, but it doesn't update instantly, visually tearing, and is generally finicky as it depends on the console window's size.

Is it possible to get the console, or something like the window's console, to do this kind of behavior?  It's okay if scrolling becomes impossible as a result.

Comment: You could use [the Windows console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) to output only at specific positions. Or use a library such as ncurses (or similar, which have ports for Windows) to split the console into smaller window-like regions.

Comment: At this point, why don't you just make a proper GUI? This is what they are for.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings - I'm trying to be lazy with all my heart, but it is hard

Comment: @AnneQuinn Ironically, your attempts at being lazy are making your life substantially harder ;)

Comment: There should come a point where you realize working hard to be lazy doesn't make sense. :-)